# Access to the $A aura object inside a softphone

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura, lightning-events

I'm trying to integrate my softphone (which uses the Lightning OpenCTI framework from api/38.0/lightning/opencti.js) with a home-made lightning component. I've got everything set up and the lightning component is ready to handle the specific event, but I can't get access to the Aura eventing pipeline to fire my event into it.

I've found this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_external.htm but window.opener is null inside my softphone.

The way I set up the softphone is through the "Call Centres" option. It basically points to a server on a VM that hosts the call centre.

Is there any way I could get to the $A aura object from inside the softphone IFrame ?